# Dividing grouped sums in data.table to get rate in one step

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks something like this:

```
Fruit       Date    Count
Apple       8/29/16 20548
Orange      8/29/16 14744
Banana      8/29/16 10605
Strawberry  8/29/16 8341
Watermelon  8/29/16 7768
Apple       8/30/16 9819
Orange      8/30/16 5858
Banana      8/30/16 3624
Strawberry  8/30/16 2595
Watermelon  8/30/16 2291
Apple       8/31/16 6662
Orange      8/31/16 6563
Banana      8/31/16 2073
Strawberry  8/31/16 1827
Watermelon  8/31/16 1738
```

How can I get sums of `Count` by `Fruit` & `Date`, and then divide the sums to produce a rate (e.g. `Banana / Apple`) in one step? Getting the sums is easy enough (note: I'm also filtering `Fruit` to only grab two at a time):

```
d.table[Fruit %in% c('Apple', 'Banana'), .(Sum = sum(Count)), .(Fruit, Date)]
```

But I'm stuck in getting to my desired output in one step:

```
Date    Rate
8/29/16 0.52
8/30/16 0.37
8/31/16 0.31
```

I should note that my actual data.table has additional columns (used just for filtering) and that I don't want to reshape my data/use another package, if possible, as the result of this operation will be plotted after filtering on multiple/changing criteria, and so I'm hoping for something easily reusable (i.e. a one-liner).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Frank thanks, I fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
d.table[Fruit %in% c('Apple', 'Banana'),
        .(Rate = sum(Count[Fruit == 'Banana']) / sum(Count[Fruit == 'Apple'])),
       .(Date)]
#       Date      Rate
# 1: 8/29/16 0.5161086
# 2: 8/30/16 0.3690804
# 3: 8/31/16 0.3111678
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(d.table)[Fruit %chin% c("Banana", "Apple")],
      Date~Fruit, value.var="Count")[, .(Date, Rate = Banana/Apple)]
#      Date      Rate
#1: 8/29/16 0.5161086
#2: 8/30/16 0.3690804
#3: 8/31/16 0.3111678
```